# load spinner works only after first drop down select

Tags: jquery, datatables, dropdownbox

My page loads and displays the  with the Loading spinner icon. Once data populates in my Data Table, subsequent selections [changes] in drop down selection does not trigger the spinner. I even put the jQuery inside the function that grabs new data to load into the Data Table. Too much code to paste the whole file, but the spinner is styled, then jQuery shows and hides it before Ajax call and after Success:

```
<style>
#div_loading_image { 
        display:none; 
        position:absolute; 
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        top: 10%;
        left: 60%;
    }
</style>
```

Then inside the  tag:

```
<div id="div_loading_image"><img id="loading_image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
```

Next, inside document ready, i get the data, set up the Data Table, add the drop down change function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
get_data(); //doing this here allows page refresh to populate page with current LP and FY selection.

var table = jQuery('#am_status').DataTable({
   scrollY:true,
   scrollX:true,
   scrollCollapse: true,
   paging:false,        
   fixedHeader: true,
   autoWidth: true,
   //dom: 'Bfrtip', //has to be here, it puts the buttons in the dom.
   dom: 'Bfrtip', 
   //buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print']
   buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print']
});

jQuery('#fy_select').on('change', function() {
    jQuery('#div_loading_image').show();
    get_data();
})
```

Then get the data:

```
 function get_data() { 

    jQuery('#div_loading_image').show();    
    var fy = jQuery('#fy_select').val();

jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://fabrik.smartstartinc.net/ncpcphp/<?php echo THIS_DIR; ?>/am_status_get_info.php",
            //contentType: "application/json",
            data: {fy: fy},
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data, XMLHttpRequest) {
                console.log(data);
                table.clear(); //otherwise the table will append to the previous Retrieve.
                var counter = 0; //to tag the dynamic fields with their own unique identifying class name.
                var index = 0;
                //console.log("data.length/before .each: " + data.length);
```

Then go through the returned data:

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index) {
```

Process the data and push it into the Data Table:

```
table.row.add([
                        info_01, info_02, info_03, info_04, info_05, info_06, info_07, info_08, info_09, info_10, info_11, info_12, info_13, info_14, info_15, info_16, info_17
                        //am_status_info[0], am_status_info[0], am_status_info[2], am_status_info[3], am_status_info[4], am_status_info[5], am_status_info[6], am_status_info[7], am_status_info[8], am_status_info[9], am_status_info[10], am_status_info[11], am_status_info[12], am_status_info[13], am_status_info[14], am_status_info[15], am_status_info[16]
                    ]).draw();
```

Then finish out the get_data() function:

```
}); //.each
                //} //for

                jQuery('#div_loading_image').hide();
                console.log("data.length/after .each: " + data.length);

                //now after page is loaded, scroll through and check the the checkboxes.
                //note that above to add checking logic would make code readability much lower.
           },
           error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
           }
        }); //.ajax
    //}, 0); //setTimeout

        setTimeout(align_table, 500); //otherwise, DataTable headers do not align with table data population.
        return false;
}
```

});

I hope that omitting some of the code does not hinder the troubleshooting. Any ideas why a div show would not trigger after subsequent selections of a drop down?

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
$(document).on('change', '#fy_select', function () {

});
```

The event `jQuery('#fy_select').on('change', function() {` just trigger based on existing DOM on event creation time..

Comment: thank you, but [a]i am already inside a $(document).ready(function () {.... then [b]inside there i have the on change. when i put your code in place, it is already inside the ready function, and it behaves the same. in other words, $(document).on('change', '#fy_select', function () { is in side of jQuery(document).ready(function (){. moving things around creates out.of.scope errors; or DataTables warning cannot be reinitialized; then i try to destroy after creation, nothing displays. don't see why when get_data() is called, it simply will not obey jQuery to show the div! thx, tho :].

Comment: again, thx for your help! i kept running into issues where initializing vars and putting functions in places in and out of document ready was running into scope errors. i finally added a <body onload="loadSpinner()">, whose code involved a jQuery("#div_loading_image"0.animate({ top: 60, left: 800 }, 1); - and all is well. your code helped me rethink where to place things and consider the different scope levels for vars and functions.+1 for your helping me move foward; but i did not check it bc i did not want to give the idea that it was the final resolution to the problem. thx again!